# Can't Recognize Touch On navigation Bar's Image View.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a View With Navigation Bar

Actually I have taken a Image View and Put it on a navigation bar....

As I want Button Not at right or Left but at somewhere on the navigation bar

By this method I can recognize touch on view but can not recognize touch on Navigation Bar ?

Can I change anything...
In this method...
Why?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {

    CGPoint p;
    p.x=0;
    p.y=0;

    p = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.nvbrCalculateBar];

    NSLog(@" %f",p.x);



    if(p.x==0 && q.x==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
```

//Load View

```
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a UITapGestureRecognizer to your UIImageView and that should do the trick

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapEvent:)];
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];

- (void)tapEvent:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
  //Do whatever you need when user taps the imageView
}
```

Also set the userInteractionEnabled of the imageView to YES to be able to receive the gesture recognizer events.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You.......:.) Very Much It works Fine...As You have return userIntercation Enabled I have tried.. A lot before...Thanks ....

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer.  It's a shame you don't have more points, because this was finally a suitable response after a day of looking at various incomplete or confusing resources.

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationBar itself is not set to return touches, since I believe its not part of the actual UIView (for which the touchesBegan) method applies. Instead, you can push various items onto the nav bar (e.g. buttons) which you can define interactions for.

See its reference [here](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html).

Answer (score 0):

USer Interaction Must be enabled of UINavigation Bar Property, And then Apply touch method..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

This should prevent your imageview to cancel the touches.